# Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'type_id' in 'field list'

Tags: php, laravel, database, function

I get this error when i tried to compile the controller of a class named Type in which i tried to create a classs called Compte, the relation is One type to Many compte.
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'type_id' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `comptes` (`password`, `type_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (hhh, 1, 2021-10-15 18:16:49, 2021-10-15 18:16:49))

The type_id does not exist in my code:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kogPR.jpg)

Comment: Please show your classes with the relationships. You probably have to define `id_type` instead of `type_id` on the relationship

Answer (score 1):

The "type_id" is not a column in the database table you are inserting into.

Answer (score 1):

Add field name in model like `protected $fillable = ['type_id',....];`
Or remove protected $fillable from model then all fields available for fillable

Answer (score 0):

That was because of you haven't column named `type_id` in your database table.

Answer (score 0):

As you write in your code, you define the `id_type` column for your table but you try to insert data to `type_id` column that doesn't exists!